# Is there a way to tell Turbolinks as portion of the page has updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have dynamically added a div onto my document with ajax and I need to tell turbo links the page has updated.

I would like to keep using `$(".comment")` instead of `$(document)` because the the .arrow class is on multiple items other then `$(".comment")`

```
$(".comment").on("click", ".arrow-down", function () {
```

Comment: Would `$(document).on('click', '.comment.arrow-down', function ()` be so bad?

Comment: Turbolinks is only about reloading the entire `<body>` when a link is clicked. That's all it does. There's is no "telling" it about anything else other than user's clicking on links.